# Generation of a constant term is observed

Tags: computer-science, recursion, recursive-algorithms

> Here's a question from a past contest conducted by ***CMI (Chennai
>   Mathematical Institute)***.
>
> [image]

---

First of all, the conditions of the question can be broken down into (my interpretation, check if incorrect):

- if $i>j$, then, $f(i,j)=f(i-1,j)$
- if $i\leq j$ **and** $i=0$, then, $f(i,j)=0$

And the *final condition begining with **otherwise*** can be restated as:

- if $i\leq j$ **and** $i\neq 0$, then, $f(i,j)=f(i-1,j)+i$

---

**DOUBTS:**

1. I am not sure but the question is apparently self-contradictory. It requires to prove $f(i,j)=\tfrac{i(i+1)}{2}$ but doesn't that lead to a contradiction to the first point? 
   Fix $j$. Increase $i$. So, from $i=0$ to $i=j$, if $f(i,j)=\tfrac{i(i+1)}{2}$ holds, then, $\forall i\geq j$, we have $f(i,j)=f(i-1,j)=\tfrac{j(j+1)}{2}$ and this can be easily understood, else, can be proven by induction. Am I missing something or is the question correct? **(My first doubt)**
2. And secondly, the question says : "if multiple conditions apply, consider the first criteria listed. Can there be any multiple criteria case? Either $i\leq j$ or $i > j$. There's no other way, right? **(My second doubt)**

Kindly clarify the doubts.

Comment: I think I agree with you about point 1, it seems that it should actually be $j(j+1)/2$ if I'm not missing something. As for point 2, this seems like a templating thing, but if you like you can think of "otherwise" as an alias for "True" (indeed this is exactly how it is done in Haskell).

Comment: Yes, but how can more than one of the criteria be **true**? That's not possible, right? I'm sorry, I don't get the relation to Haskell. I haven't come across the term before.

Comment: I think the first rule have to be $f(i,j) = f(i,j-1)$ in order for this to be true.

Comment: And what about my second doubt? More than one of the criteria can not really be **true**, right? So, multiple conditions won't hold simultaneously.

Comment: My point is that "Otherwise" could be argued to technically apply at all times, but it already implies that the previous two possibilities were ruled out. The first two are indeed mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the problem is poorly worded, and the proposed answer is wrong.

> 1. I am not sure but the question is apparently self-contradictory. It requires to prove $f(i,j)=\tfrac{i(i+1)}{2}$ but   [...]  
>      Fix $j$. Increase $i$. So, from $i=0$ to $i=j$ ...

...just iterate for $\,i \le j\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
f(0,j) & = 0 \\
f(1, j) &= f(0,j) + 1 = 1 \\
f(2, j) &= f(1,j) + 2 = 1 + 2 \\
 \ldots \\
f(i, j) &= f(i-1,j) + i = 1+2+\ldots i = \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \\
\end{align}
$$

So in the end:

$$
f(i, j) = \begin{cases} \frac{i(i+1)}{2} \quad\quad i \le j \\ \frac{j(j+1)}{2} \quad\quad i \gt j\end{cases}
$$

That can be written as $\,f(i,j)=\frac{\min(i,j)\big(\min(i,j)+1\big)}{2}\,$, but it's still nowhere close to the given answer.

> 2. And secondly, the question says : "if multiple conditions apply, consider the first criteria listed. Can there be any multiple criteria case? Either $i\leq j$ or $i > j$.

I guess what the problem *meant* to say was that in the case $\,i \le j\,$ rule #2 applies first, then rule #3 (only) if $\,i \ne 0\,$. That's *very* poorly worded IMHO.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo from my side, I just tried to convey that the value gets fixed to $j(j+1)/2$ once $i\geq j$. And yes, I agree with your points.

Comment: @Mathbg Edited the answer accordingly, and also included the full expression for $\,f\,$.